# Laravel | Отсортировать города по алфавиту и объединить результат в одну букву

Tags: laravel, сортировка, коллекции

Тайтл темы явно не соответствует вопросу, потому-что мне не хватает эрудированности сформулировать вопрос, но суть звучит следующим образом:

Имеется таблица городов, при получении коллекции используется сортировка по алфавиту, **sortBy('name')** , при выводе через **@foreach()** необходимо получить первую букву отсортированных городов. К примеру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли в **Laravel** способ чтобы сделать подобное? Или же необходимо ручками писать фильтр?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Группировку по первой букве названия можно сделать так:

```
$cities = City::sortBy('name')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function($item) { 
        return mb_substr($item->name, 0, 1); 
    });
```

В шаблоне выводить так:

```
@foreach($cities as $letter => $letterCities)
    <h3>{{ $letter }}</h3>
    @foreach($letterCities as $city)
        <p>{{ $city->name }}</p>
    @endforeach        
@endforeach
```